# Update an array inside an object with unique value in react with hook

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, react-hooks

I have a two selection list from where i can select the value

list one= "A", "B"

list two = "C", "D", "E", "F"

I have a state in react
 `const [filterTags, setFilterTags] = useState({ one: [], two: [] });`

I can pass one val at a time from any of the list in `updateValue(val)`
I need to update the filterTags in such a vay that if its `val` is from list `one` that is  `A` or `B` it should update the state like this
`{one:["A"]: two:[]}`

```
const updateValue = (val) => {
        if (val === 'A' || val === 'B') {
            setFilterTags({ one: val });
        } else {
            setFilterTags({ ...filterTags, two: val });
        }
    };
```

if I pass `A C C D B A E C` one by one it should update the array with the unique values and the output should be

```
{one:["A"]: two:[]} //passing A
{one:["A"]: two:["C"]} //passing C
{one:["A"]: two:["C"]} // same since C is already there in two on passing C
{one:["A"]: two:["C","D"]} //passing D
{one:["A","B"]: two:["C","D"]}  //passing B
{one:["A","B"]: two:["C","D"]} //same since A is already present in one on //passing A
{one:["A","B"]: two:["C","D","E"]} //passing E
{one:["A","B"]: two:["C","D","E"]}// final output on passing C
```

it should update the respective element with unique values
right now the above code can just update a single value

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that you are only adding elements that are not already there, you can use the `includes` function on the arrays to check for that, and you also want to make sure that you are keeping all the previous content.

A potential solution could be to do the following:

```
const updateValue = (val) => {
  if (val === 'A' || val === 'B') {
    if(!filterTags.one.includes(val)) {
      setFilterTags((prev) => ({ one: [...prev.one, val], two: prev.two }));
    }
  } else {
    if(!filterTags.two.includes(val)) {
      setFilterTags((prev) => ({ one: prev.one, two: [...prev.two, val] }));
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) option, when setting the state, to get the previous value (`prev`), and use spread to create a new state with the previous and updated values. Use a Set to maintain unique values.

```
const updateValue = (val) => {
  if (val === 'A' || val === 'B') {
    setFilterTags(prev => ({ ...prev, one: [...new Set([...prev.one, val])] }));
  } else {
    setFilterTags(prev => ({ ...prev, two: [...new Set([...prev.two, val])] }));
  }
};
```

How there is too much code repetition here, since the logic for setting the state is identical, and just the key changes, so you can refactor it:

```
const updateValue = (val) => {
  const key = val === 'A' || val === 'B' ? 'one' : 'two';
  
  setFilterTags(prev => ({ ...prev, [key]: [...new Set([...prev[key], val])] }));
};
```

You can also use `Array.includes` as [suggested by Houssam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69661789/5157454) to avoid updating the state:

```
const updateValue = (val) => {
  const key = val === 'A' || val === 'B' ? 'one' : 'two';

  setFilterTags(prev => {
    const key = val === 'A' || val === 'B' ? 'one' : 'two';
    
    return prev[key].includes(val)
      ? prev
      : { ...prev, [key]: [...prev[key], val] };
  });
};
```

Comment: it will return a set not an array i think

Comment: The Set is converted back to an array using spread - `[...new Set([.`

Answer (score 0):

This commented code can help you:

```
const updateValue = (val) => {
  //creating a temporary copy of filterTags
  const tempFilterTags = {...filterTags}
  //checking if val is A or B and if finterTag.one does not contain the value
  if ((val === 'A' || val === 'B') && filterTags.one.find(el=> el == val) === null) {
    //if success, push the value for field one and update filterTag
    tempFilterTags.one.push(val)
    setFilterTags(tempFilterTags)
  } 
  //checking if val is C, D, E of F and if finterTag.two does not contain the value
  if ((val === 'C' || val === 'D' || val === 'E' || val === 'F') && filterTags.two.find(el=> el == val) === null) {
    //if success, push the value for field two and update filterTag
    tempFilterTags.two.push(val)
    setFilterTags(tempFilterTags)
  } 
};
```